# Flat file Schema (Delimited) creation wizard in Biztalk server 2015

Tags: xsd, biztalk, flat-file

i want to add nested child record with elements in **Positional File** (Flat File schema Creation wizard) using Biztalk,
for Eg. Generated instance to be like this: `<Root><Child_Rec1><Child_Ele>ELEMENT</Child_Ele></Child_Rec1></Root>`

Comment: 1) There is no BizTalk Server 2015.  2) Can you give an example of the flat file with more details?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, what you are asking for is not possible with the Flat File Disassemler.

It is not supported to have Delimited content within Positional Content.

The way to work around this is the split the delimited content in a Map and set the target fields.

Comment: It is possible to have mix of delimited and positional contents in one schema, I have done this, however it is unclear that this is what the OP is asking tom me.

Comment: I tried this with the Wizard and you can't make a Delimited within a Positional.  The other way around yes.  And you can only switch patterns once.

Comment: Yes, positional within delimited (in fact most positional files are partly delimited as records are delimited by CR LF etc.).   The Wizard is possibly more limited as with the schema editor I can have a record that transitions between the two multiple times, by having some of the delimited fields defined as a positional record.